# Exporting Tensorboard computation graph as vector graphics

Tags: tensorboard

In Tensorboard there is a button save the computation graph as a png, is there a way to export it as vector graphics like eps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save in svg format with [SVG Crowbar](https://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/)

1. Bookmark the "SVG Crowbar 2"
2. Open tensorboard and the graph you want
3. Open your bookmarks tab, click the bookmark (it may take a long time)
4. Download the corresponding svg (it will output lots of svg, I'm not sure which one is which)

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely! When you download all of these (by clicking "Download") look for the one called svg.svg, which is the main graph.

Comment: And if you don't want to click on "Download" for all SVGs search (ctrl + f) for the one named "#svg.style-scope tf-graph-scene", that's the main graph. Thanks for the answer, spared me a lot of trouble.